# (2/2) QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'homestead' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` =

Tags: php, laravel, registration, homestead

I want to try the registration form of laravel where I have to insert my database information in the `.env` file.

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=blog
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=admin
```

In my `config/database.php` file I also change the values to my current database

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'blog'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'admin'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

But, I get the error that my `homestead` database is unknown. I have know idea where the information comes from ? I don't have connect a database with this name in any file? or should there a third file to change?

Comment: Very strange...and you're sure this is the same exact `.env` from the project? It should be pulling from the `.env` first, then the `config/database.php` second.

Comment: Check your `homestead.yaml` file. Maybe something to do with it having the database name set to `homestead` when you init homestead and maybe forgot to change it.

Comment: Sometime it's due to configuration cache, try  to clear cache like 'php artisan config:cache'. It might work.

Answer (score 5):

@weristsam
You should clear the cache after changing in .env file

run the following commands

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: thank you so much vishal! after delete all my cache it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

After successfully modifying the .env file and you're still receiving unknown homestead database, don't stress the thing is Laravel is still reading the previous cache and compiled view. Just clear all by using the following command:

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear
```